# Different loop entries lied different ratio between two function in c#

Tags: c#, performance

I check performance of two function behind loop of around 65,000,000.

I checked it once (loop of 65,00,00) against addition loop of 10 and the ratio between the two functions not the same:

Function 1 called `DepthToBytes`

Function 2 called `bitmapToStream`

Summery result:

```
// Without the addition loop of 10
depthToBytes(): sum: 490
bitmapToStream(): sum: 1475

// Contain the addition loop of 10
depthToBytes(): sum: 11575
bitmapToStream(): sum: 24556
```

I can understand why `11575 != 10 * 490` and  `24556 != 1475 * 10`. (I can control the first run (without the addition loop) when the CPU low).

But why the ratio is different:

```
 11575 / (10 * 490) != 24556 / (1475 * 10)
```

why `2.362 != 1.664`?

EDIT: the calling code look like this:

```
long sum = 0;
long sum2 = 0;
for (int pixelIndex = 0; pixelIndex < 65,000,000; pixelIndex++) {
  var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
  depthToBytes():
  long temp = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
  Console.WriteLine("DepthToBytes(): " + temp);
  sum += temp;
  Console.WriteLine("DepthToBytes(): sum: " + sum);

  var sw2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
  Stream s = BitmapToStream(bitmap);:
  temp = sw2.ElapsedMilliseconds;
  Console.WriteLine("BitmapToStream(): " + temp);
  sum2 += temp;
  Console.WriteLine("BitmapToStream(): sum2: " + sum2);
}
```

Comment: The code inside the method isn't relevant, the two function both behind the same loop of 65,000,000 and I check the time only within the function

Comment: It may well be relevant. But at least show the calling code.

Comment: Inside the function have calculate pure c#

Comment: That didn't really add any information. "Pure C#" is the norm, not the exception.

Answer (score 2):

Your performance test makes a lot of mistakes that bring the accuracy way down.

- You don't want to start a new `Stopwatch` in every iteration of the loop. Instead, separate the loop in two, and wrap each of the loops in a single `Stopwatch`. Divide the milliseconds you get by number of iterations, and you have time per iteration. Otherwise you're just accumulating loads of measurement errors. Not to mention that it will quite unfairly assign the cost of garbage collection from one method to another; test each in separation to get a better idea. If the first one allocates 1 MiB and the second one just a single byte, it might still mean the second one will get the whole cost of garbage collection, even though the bottleneck is in the first one.
- You're completely ignoring the cost of `Console.WriteLine` and the string additions. This can actually hurt a lot.
- There's no way to tell without seeing the inside of the code, but it's quite likely the two methods have very different memory pressure patterns. Again, this will tend to break your measurements. Separate the loops, and you'll get better data for each.
- Use a profiler. It will easily show you where your CPU, memory and synchronization costs are. Guessing around is a terrible idea, your way is halway there (though very misleading, see above), a full blown profiler can give you further great clues.

Comment: Console.WriteLine is temporary and not relevant to the timing. Create new Stopwatch (temporary too) doesn't change anything. I wand check only the functions and without additional commands inside the loop and second function using the first one..

Comment: @RoyShmuli how do you know that `Console.WriteLine` is not relevant? Have you tried to remove it from the loop?

Comment: @RoyShmuli Are you even listening? *You can't measure just the time inside the function, because that will accumulate measurement errors over the 65M iterations.* If you want to only check the functions, make a new loop for testing, and only run the single function inside of that, while keeping the `Stopwatch` outside. That's the only way to at least somehow reliably measure the time a given method takes to execute. It will still be affected by things like JIT compilation and GC, but it's a start.